# ReactNative Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react-native I'm writing an app flat list contains cards but I get this error
here is my code

```
          constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            GridListItems: [ // Home Screen Cards Data [STATIC]
              { id: 1 , key: "222" , img: 'https://i.ibb.co/Lt88dTg/makeup.png' },
               { id: 2 ,key: "2" , img: 'https://i.ibb.co/H4NRnZK/Photographers.png'},
               { id: 3 ,key: "Wedding Halls" , img: 'https://i.ibb.co/b2JdtHW/wedding-Hall.png'},
               { id: 4 ,key: "Wedding Planners" , img: 'https://i.ibb.co/g95HhKT/image-1.jpg'},
               { id: 5 ,key: "Ateliers for Dresses" , img: 'https://i.ibb.co/g4ksBDk/wedding.png'},
            ]
        };
    }
    renderItem = ({item}) => {
      return(
        <TouchableOpacity key={item.id.toString()}
        style={styles.GridViewContainer}
    >
      </TouchableOpacity>
      )

    }
render () {
  const carousel = this.mainCarousel(1); // Rendering the Carousel 

  return (
     <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>

    { this.gradient }
    <ScrollView
      style={styles.scrollview}
      scrollEventThrottle={200}
      directionalLockEnabled={true}
    >
        {/* { carousel }  */}

        <FlatList

        data={ this.state.GridListItems }
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
        renderItem={ this.renderItem }
        numColumns={2}
        initialNumToRender={6}
/>
    </ScrollView>

</SafeAreaView>

);
}
```

but I get Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. See https://fb .me/ react-warning-keys for more information.%s,

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you've posted the wrong part of your components. Do you have a `.map()` or any other iterating function inside of a render function? The warning should tell you which component causes the issue

Comment: no i don't have .map() or anything 
here is the project github repo can you see what's wrong it's really furstrating :D
https://github.com/Ov3rControl/Weddi

Answer (score 1):

Check if this solves the issue : `keyExtractor={({item, index}) => item.id.toString()}`
If not , 
Use this instead : 
 `keyExtractor={(item, index) =>`${index}`}` or

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this gets at the real issue. If the poster believes his id's are unique, then there might be another problem. Maybe some ids are duplicated or not defined, or maybe the same item is in the list twice.

Comment: keyExtractor={({item, index}) => item.id.toString()} Get me undefined item.id

the rest isn't working as well

Answer (score 1):

I would make an console.log statement in the keyExtractor to see what you are getting:

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
  console.log('item', item);
  return item.id.toString();
}}
```

This way you see what data is passed into the function and return the relevant part.

By the way: a Flatlist is a scrollable list, so you do not need to wrap it in a ScrollView. See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist